# Using SPI to get higher sampling rate from ADC module vs using ADC on microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc, spi

I am currently looking at a microcontroller, and I would like to use ADC on Arduino but found out that the Arduino has a limited sampling rate. Is it possible to us SPI communication with a separate ADC module to get higher sampling rate?
I don't have any circuitry right but I want to know if it is common to use SPI with a separate ADC module to get high sampling rate.

Comment: Sure but since it is an Arduino the SPI speed could also be limited. Why don't you describe with some numbers what speca you now have and what specs you need? Many MCUs have much faster and better built-in ADCs than the Arduino, so do consider moving away from it if your needs have overgrown what it can provide.

Comment: @Justme yes, the devil in the details, and those are certainly lacking in the question. Source impedance wouldn't hurt, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an "Arduino" compatible module such as the STM32F103C8T6-based ones, which have claimed "12-bit" and "1us" ADC peripherals. Read the datasheet with a jaundiced eye to determine the actual performance. You can't expect to match the performance of a fast external ADC from a top-line company.

I think it would be more common to use an external ADC to get better performance than the on-board 10-bit ADC.

You should think about where the data is going and whether the processor is up to handling it, beside just the raw ADC speed.

Also, you can make the ADC in the ATMega328 run 5-10x faster if you don't use the analogRead function, but allow it to free run with interrupts. Perhaps with some loss in performance.

Comment: Just in case someone reads this and gets excited, it is not that simple to get actual 12 bit resolution from STM32 ADC. 1us sampling is definitely out of the question. You'd need many times that for sampling, ideally with HW oversampling. Even then for really demanding applications one has to temporarily suspend digital processing and I/O while doing sampling, not to mention careful PCB design requirements.

Comment: @Maple Yes, I will edit in some scare quotes. It's the datasheet "big print" which the small taketh away. Just for context, OP is looking at (sort of) 10 bits and ~9kHz maximum using the Arduino library functions and ATMega328p.

Comment: Very good edits. Indeed, in the race for sampling rate many keep forgetting that the samples should be processed somehow. And as @Justme mentioned in the comments, to get data back from external device might take more time than actual sampling

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic here.  If I increase the SPI clock rate to about 1Mhz, and receive data from ADC at 1Mhz, how does Arduino process the data when it cannot even match upto 1Mhz incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to know if it is common to use SPI with a separate ADC module
> to get high sampling rate*

It's quite common and you'll find that an external ADC is usually much better than an internal ADC regarding performance and accuracy. Plus, if you use two external ADCs you can arrange for them to simultaneously sample should that be a requirement (such as in power calculations where v and i are sampled together).

Comment: Using external ADC for accuracy - yes, it is quite common. For performance - not so much. You will be limited by the communication speed which most likely will eliminate any performance gains.

Comment: @Andy, Lets say that I increased the SPI clock rate to 1Mhz, and receive data from ADC at 1Mhz. How does Arduino process the incoming data when it cannot match up to the incoming 1Mhz data.

Comment: The arduino sets the speed at which data is clocked from the ADC. You cannot go faster than what the Arduino can handle @Sam